# Литература для изучения MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите, что можно почитать для изучения MS SQL. Опыта работы с БД нет.
Видел темы: литература для My SQL, но для MS SQL не встретил.

Comment: MS SQL это достаточно большой и сложный продукт, а точнее несколько продуктов под одним брендом. Вы для каких целей хотите изучить: разработка, администрирование, может быть отчетность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта попроще: [Душан Петкович](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19688054/)

Эта поглубже: [Бен-Ган](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31231023/)

Ещё можно вспомнить [книгу Грабера](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/110336/). Она, правда, не по MS SQL, а про SQL "вообще", но её очень хвалят (врать не буду, не читал)

Comment: Есть два издания книги Грабера (Грубера) на русском: одна словно бы переведена Промтом, другая - нормальная.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  А издательство у них разное я так понимаю?

Comment: @alladuh - да, издательства разные. Хорошее издание у "Лори" (по-моему, так). Бродит по сети в формате djvu. Плохое бродит по сети в формате pdf. Я когда-то начал с него, потом удивлялся, почему многие хвалят Грабера. Потом нашёл второе издание.

Answer (score 1):

Мне Петкович не пошёл, а вот Бондарь понравился: [https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Бондарь_Александр_Григорьевич_Microsoft_SQL_Server?id=WVU-CQAAQBAJ](https://play.google.com/store/books/details/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_Microsoft_SQL_Server?id=WVU-CQAAQBAJ)

Ну и Флёнов неплохо писал: http://www.flenov.info/books.php?id=10